# Error PM|Fatal|WebSocket.doHandshake|Indicates the redirection #326

Tags: c#, websocket, websocket-sharp

I keep running into this error. Here is the code that I wrote for a client connecting to a websocket server(written in java but that shouldnt matter I believe)

I am using websocketsharp library for this.

```
enter code here

    var unq = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var url = "wss://<<some_server.com>>/sock/849/"+ unq+"/websocket";

    _client = new WebSocket(url);
    _client.SetCookie(new WebSocketSharp.Net.Cookie("Cookie","SESSION=" + _session));

    _client.OnOpen += _client_OnOpen;
    _client.OnError += _client_OnError;
    _client.OnClose += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("closed");
    _client.OnMessage += _client_OnMessage;
    _client.Connect();
```

When connect is called it gives this error and closes the connection.

Error PM|Fatal|WebSocket.doHandshake|Indicates the redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out - it did not like Kerberos authentication, so I ended up changing it to NTLM

```
        _collabPlatform.AllowedAuthenticationProtocol = SipAuthenticationProtocols.Ntlm;
```

Comment: where is this configured?